# grails searchable - avoid index for embedded entity

Tags: grails, lucene, indexing, searchable

I'm playing around with searchable and ran into a problem I can't solve myself.

There are two entities:

```
class Activity {
    static searchable = {
        only = ["title", "place"]
    }

    String title
    String place
    ActivityImage image
}

class ActivityImage {
    static searchable = false

    String name
    byte[] content
}
```

Now I want Activity to be searchable but not the ActivityImage. Nevertheless, searchable tries to create an index also taking the ActivityImage into account, which crashes the Tomcat with an OutOfMemoryException. I already tried a bunch of things but couldn't figure out how to keep searchable from doing so :(

Does someone have an idea?

Cheers,

Moritz

Comment: Is that DSL correct?

this example ( http://groovytard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/quick-journey-through-grails-searchable.html ) seems to suggest that you want a map. 

    static searchable = {
        only : 'title'
    }
    
    or static searchable = [ only : 'title' ]

Comment: According to http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Mapping+-+Not+All+Properties the syntax for only and except is

    `static searchable = {
        except = ["version", "createdAt"]
        ...
    }` but I've added an attribute "place" to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `static serchable` is making your `ActivityImage` searchable.  If it should not be searchable then don't put anything in that class (i.e. remove `static searchable = false`).

Comment: Didn't help. It's still trying to index it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the searchable plugin when creating the index it does a query on all properties. I've logged an issue here: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSEARCHABLE-233